# How can I know if a Java 19 Structured Concurrency StructuredTaskScope is shutdown ( canceled )?

Tags: java, java-19, structured-concurrency

A Java 19 ShutdownOnFailure scope also allows for explicit cancellation of all tasks using the shutdown method. How can I know if the scope has been shutdown? The API includes an isShutdown method, but it is private.

Here is some (incomplete) code just to illustrate a possible use, where a scope is canceled some time after starting by the owner calling shutdown.

I guess that after a join() I could issue another scope.fork() and check if if returns a future to a canceled task but that seems weird.  Is that the way to go?

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
try (StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()) {
    Future<Integer> numOrders = scope.fork(Business::getNumItemsFromRequest);
    Future<Double> price = scope.fork(Business::getPriceFromDB);
    
    Business.sleepFor(500);
    scope.shutdown(); // cancels all the scope tasks
    //numOrders.cancel(true); // cancel just one task
    
    scope.join(); // wait for all tasks
    try {
        scope.throwIfFailed();
        // how would I know if scope was shutdown before all tasks completed?
        System.out.println("Scope Completed Without Errors ( But possibly canceled ) ");
        double amount = numOrders.get() * price.get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working code (as an experiment) located [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_java_loom/tree/main/egg_StackOverflow_74464598).

Given this:

```
var result = "error";

try (var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()) {
     var numOrders = scope.fork(() -> taskGetNumItemsFromRequest()); 
     var price = scope.fork(() -> taskGetPriceFromDB());

    if (doShutdown) {
        scope.shutdown();
    }
            
    scope.join();          
    scope.throwIfFailed();

    result = numOrders.resultNow() + " " + price.resultNow();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (ex != null) {
        System.err.println("caught ex: " + ex.getClass());
        System.err.println("caught ex message: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

then this line:

```
    result = numOrders.resultNow() + " " + price.resultNow();
```

will throw an Exception if the scope is shutdown. [See the code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk19/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/Future.java) for `Future.resultNow()`.

It's unclear if you want to distinguish between other exception cases, such as *closing* the scope, or an exception thrown by a subtask? If you do want to distinguish, it would help to explain the reason in the question (i.e. the ultimate goal).

In general, there should be two paths: the happy-path for `result` and then a path of an exception being thrown (for whatever reason).

Comment: Yes, I realized that any of the resultNows would throw an exception.  I think since a scope can be shutdown as a unit there is merit in an imperative interrogation to weather it was canceled before encountering exception logic.

Answer (score 2):

SUGGESTION: Encapsulate the functionality you need in a subclass.

From the Incubator documentation:

> https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/jdk.incubator.concurrent/jdk/incubator/concurrent/StructuredTaskScope.html
>
> **Extending StructuredTaskScope**
>
> StructuredTaskScope can be extended, and the handleComplete
> overridden, to implement policies other than those implemented by
> ShutdownOnSuccess and ShutdownOnFailure. The method may be overridden
> to, for example, collect the results of subtasks that complete with a
> result and ignore subtasks that fail. It may collect exceptions when
> subtasks fail. It may invoke the shutdown method to shut down and
> cause join to wakeup when some condition arises.
>
> A subclass will typically define methods to make available results,
> state, or other outcome to code that executes after the join method. A
> subclass that collects results and ignores subtasks that fail may
> define a method that returns a collection of results. A subclass that
> implements a policy to shut down when a subtask fails may define a
> method to retrieve the exception of the first subtask to fail.

Comment: So for example override shutdown() to set a boolean wasShutdown?